# Customize Color1 in moderncv

Tags: errors, color, overleaf, moderncv

I tried to look at some suggested solutions from previous answers to redefine color1 with the command:

```
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.67, 0.76, 0.152}% Dark Blue
```

The color I want is (Hex: #434C98 , RGB: 67, 76, 152) as in the following figure:
[image]

Unfortunately the results I am getting is the following:

[image]

Sample Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')


\moderncvstyle{banking}   


\moderncvcolor{blue}      

%\definecolor{b}{rgb}{0.67, 0.76, 0.152}
%\colorlet{color1}{b}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.67, 0.76, 0.152}% Dark Blue


\colorlet{languagecolor}{color1}
\colorlet{nolanguagecolor}{color2}
\newcount\languagecount
\newcommand\languageknowledge[2]
  {%
    % if you change the 4cm you can change the distance, the 4cm is the space
    % reserved for the language's name, immediately after it the dots are
    % printed.
    \makebox[14.2cm][l]{\textbf{#1}}%
    %\hfill % if you want the dots to be at the right margin
    \languagecount=0
    \loop\ifnum\languagecount<#2
      \advance\languagecount1
      \textcolor{languagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
    \repeat
    \loop\ifnum\languagecount<7
      \advance\languagecount1
      \textcolor{nolanguagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
    \repeat
  }




\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{first sec}{family}
%\title{Computer Science}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{City}{Country}
\phone[mobile]{+000000000}                   % optional, remove / comment the 

\email{fatmah.hussain.alqahtani@hotmail.com}                               % 
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle


%private sect
\small{some brief intro ..............................................................................................}

\section{Professional Experience}
 \begin{itemize}
 
 \item{\cventry{Jan 2018--2019}{Organization}{Position}{City, Country}{}{\vspace{4pt}Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description}}
 \end{itemize}
 

\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Please does anyone have any workaround to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color specification `{rgb}{0.67, 0.76, 0.152}` is not identical to `RGB: 67, 76, 152`. To get the blue color you show in your question, you could simply use

```
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{67, 76, 152}
```

or

```
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{434C98}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks a lot